# White screen if I use react native navigation in combination with the "I18nextProvider" of "react-i18next"

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-i18next, react-navigation-stack

Lately I have been trying to translate my React Native application into multiple languages using the "react-i18next" library.

The moment I try to enter "I18nextProvider" (so I don't have to enter the import on each individual component) above my navigation, the application becomes with an inexplicably white screen.

How can I solve the problem?

In my App.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createNativeStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import MainTabNavigator from './src/navigation/MainTabNavigator';
import {I18nextProvider} from 'react-i18next';
import i18n from 'i18next';
// Others imports

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <I18nextProvider i18n={i18n}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Register" component={Register} />
          <Stack.Screen name="ResetPassword" component={ResetPassword} />
          <Stack.Screen
            name="MainTabNavigator"
            component={MainTabNavigator}
            options={{headerShown: false}}
          />
          {/* Others Stack.Screens */}
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </I18nextProvider>
  );
}
```

My i18next.js:

```
import i18next from "i18next";
import { initReactI18next } from "react-i18next";
import * as RNLocalize from 'react-native-localize';
import en from "../translations/en.json";
import it from "../translations/it.json";

// I detect the language of the system
const locales = RNLocalize.getLocales();
const userPreferredLocale = locales[0].languageCode;

// I create resources for languages
export const languageResources = {
   en: { translation: en },
   it: { translation: it },
}

// I set the configuration
i18next.use(initReactI18next).init({
   compatibilityJSON: "v3",
   lng: userPreferredLocale,
   fallbackLng: "en",
   resources: languageResources,
})

export default i18next;
```